# Create a netty server to pass off messages to be processed and then send the responses back

Tags: nio, netty

I am creating a POC when I have a server that takes requests from clients. Then puts those requests in a pool which another thread pool processes those request and put them back into an output pool. The server should take a response from the pool and send it back to the original requester. I know how to code this with using netty but I would really like to use netty for this POC. I've got through the examples but have not found anything similar. 
Is this possible using netty?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like there was a similar question before (one of the last questions in the list)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222134/how-does-downstream-events-work-in-jbosss-netty

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I think you are looking for the ExecutionHandler. You can use the ExecutionHandler to build some SEDA like architecture. In current master branch (upcomming 4.0) we are currently working on making it even more flexible by allowing to use different ExecutionHandlers for different kind of events.